# Convention result and code error C++ int foo (...)

Tags: c++, rules, boolean

In Linux for example when i use batch if error code is 0 thats good, but what is the convention in C++ ?

when int (or bool) is equal to one we say that's true, but what must be the return of such function in C++ ?

Answer (score 6):

In C++ it is common to use boolean return to indicate true for success, and false for failure.

It is also common to use an integer return value where zero indicates success, and non-zero to indicate failure or any other condition (often negative numbers can indicate errors, while positive indicate some other outcome).

Whichever approach you choose, the important thing is to document it and be consistent throughout the code base.

Comment: There is another convention in which zero is false and non-zero is true.

Answer (score 3):

In C and its runtime library 0 means success (sometimes polling errno is required).

In C++ world is more colourful:

- bool for success/failure
- enumeration if there are more states
- exceptions for ... well exceptional cases and object construction/destruction; sometimes they are not available or allowed (mostly embedded platforms, sometimes games to maximize performance)

DON'T mix bool usage convention and "0", result is just plain confusing code(see example). If you happen to need multiple values use enumeration, additional return parameter or exception depending on situation.

introduced bool and '0' code confusion:

```
// sorry for abuse of "C" for educational purposes
bool isSame(s1,s2) { return s1==s2; }
int isSame2(s1, s2) { return strcmp(s1.cstr(), s2.cstr()); } 

if (isSame(..) && !isSame2(..)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A C++ function or method can return a `bool` value like `true` or `false`. A program (i.e. the `main` function) must return an `int` value, for example `0` to report 'success'.

Comment: ok so the result of the main get the same behaviour than the shell :-)
Thank You

Comment: Yes the result of main *is* the value that will be seen by the shell.

Comment: @Chris - the value seen by the shell is influenced by what is returned from `main`.  They are not necessarily the same value though.  Try returning 1,024 and you will probably get zero in the shell!

Comment: Technically, there's no guarantee on how return values of `main` are mapped "from outside". The only guarantees are that returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `0` (which may be the same thing) will report successful completion, and returning `EXIT_FAILURE` will report error; any other value is implementation-defined. That said, on both Unix and Windows the translation is direct.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C functions that return an integer usually return greater-than or equal to zero for success and -1 for failure.  When -1 is returned, `errno` is usually set to provide a more specific error.  Zero indicates a generic success where numbers greater than zero are assumed to be successful and provide additional detail.

Consider something like `recvfrom()`.  A return value of -1 indicates outright failure with `errno` set to a detailed code.  A return value of zero means that the socket was shutdown in an orderly fashion and that additional calls will not return data.  A return value greater than zero means that data was received and the number of bytes received is what was returned.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you to be asking two questions:

- how do you return program status in c++
- how do functions return status in c++

Basic answers follow.

Typically the program (main()) returns 0 for success, and other values - errors - for failure

If a function can either succeed or fail, it is, typically, typed as **bool** and returns **true** or **false**.

If a function can return multiple values it will, typically, return **int** or **enum** values.

Try throwing exceptions for those cases which are exceptional.