# decide return type in function body

Tags: c++

What I want to do:

```
 foo(int x){
        if (x>=3)
            return x;
        else
            return "less than three";
 }
```

I have looked at using templates, but I'm not sure how to set the return type based on a condition like this.

Edit: I know there are other ways to do this, but I was trying to get it all inside a function. Clearly it's not as easy as I wanted it to be, at least in C++. Thank you for your answers

Comment: What would you declare the type of `foo` to be?

Comment: if all else fails `auto foo(){}`

Comment: You could create a custom type that can represent multiple types (i.e. a variant). But stepping back a bit, why exactly do you need this? Perhaps there's a different approach for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unless there's implicit conversion what you're asking for is impossible in a strongly typed language like C++

Comment: You can't do this with templates, they're resolved at compile time. C is statically-typed, you can't determine types at runtime.

Comment: @frslm look at [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in C++17 and later, or [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) in earlier versions.

Comment: A function can have only one return type.   It can't have two distinct `return` statements that return incompatible types, since there is no type that can represent both  (e.g. it can't return `int` in `return x`, and a string literal in another `return` statement).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use templates for your problem since template types are resolved during compile time.

The only way i see to make your program work is to use [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) if you have c++17 and [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/variant.html) otherwise. Then your function would look like

```
std::variant<int, std::string> foo(int x) {
    if (x>=3)
        return x;
    else
        return "less than three";
 }
```

Comment: How do you know the type contained in variant when the function returns?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic `std::variant` has methods to tell you which alternative is contained.

Comment: That's what makes it preferable to `union` (it's essentially a fancy discriminated union).

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic you use `std::variant::index()` or `std::holds_alternative()` to know what type is in the `variant`.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use std::to_string on `x` if its greater than or equal to 3, then after do `if` returned string is NOT equal to 3, then change its type back to integer. I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it simple by writing as follows:

```
int foo(int x){
    if(x>=3)
        return x;
    else
        return 0; // Or any number less than 3
}
```

Then go to the caller class, and if the returned value is `0`, then you can print `less than three`.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you have to define something as the return type to your function. However you can make the return type ambiguous through various means, some better than others.

If the function always returns type `int` unless something goes wrong you can create a wrapper type that contains either a successful result or an error.

```
Maybe<int> m = foo(3);
if (m.is_error) {
    // Stuff
} else {
    // Different stuff
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157098/) for more detail

---

If the function always returns one of a few types you can return a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
std:tuple<int, string> foo(int x) {
     if (x >= 3) {
         return std::make_tuple(x, "");
     }
     return std::make_tuple(0, "less than three");
}
```

```
auto result = foo(4);
if (!std::get<1>(result).empty()) {
    // An error is present
}
```

```
// In C++11
int num;
string err;
std::tie(num, err) = foo(3);
if (!err.empty()) { 
    // An error is present 
}
```

```
// In C++17
int num;
string err;
auto [num, err] = foo(3);
if (!err.empty()) { 
    // An error is present 
}
```

---

In C++17 you can (and should) use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of a tuple. [`std::variant:::index()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) or [`std::holds_alternative()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) will tell you which type is held:

```
std::variant<int, string> foo(int x) {
    std::variant<int, string> result;
    if (x >= 3) {
        result = x;
    }
    else {
        result = "less than three";
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
auto result = foo(3);
if (result.index() == 1) {
    // An error is present
}
```

```
auto result = foo(3);
if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(result)) {
    // An error is present
}
```

---

And the *technically possible* but **extremely terribly stupid idea**, you can always return `void*` and try and figure things out later:

```
void* reallyBad(int x) {
    if (x >= 3) {
        return new int(x);
    }
    return new string("Less than three");
}
```

I include this only because *technically* you are deciding the return type in the function body, but it is effectively impossible to deduce the returned type outside of the function, and would likely introduce many memory leaks and hard to debug errors.

Comment: You should use `std::variant` instead of `std::tuple`.

Comment: Added `std::variant`

Comment: Also, `auto [num, err] = foo(3);` syntax was added in C++17. In C++11, you have to use `std::tie()` instead