# How does one deal with various errors in statically typed languages (or when typing in general)

Tags: python, c++, typing, static-typing

For context, my primary langauge is Python, and I'm just beginning to use annotations. This is in preparation for learning C++ (and because, intuitively, it feels better).

---

I have something like this:

```
from models import UserLocation
from typing import Optional
import cluster_module
import db
def get_user_location(user_id: int, data: list) -> Optional[UserLocation]:
    loc = UserLocation.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).one_or_none()
    if loc:
        return loc
    try:
        clusters = cluster_module.cluster(data)
    except ValueError:
        return None # cluster throws an error if there is not enough data to cluster

    if list(clusters.keys()) == [-1]:
        return None # If there is enough data to cluster, the cluster with an index of -1 represents all data that didn't fit into a cluster. It's possible for NO data to fit into a cluster.
    loc = UserLocation(user_id=user_id, location = clusters[0].center)
    db.session.add(loc)
    db.session.commit()
    return loc
```

So, I use `typing.Optional` to ensure that I can return `None` in case there's an error (if I understand correctly, the static-typing-language equivalent of this would be to return a null pointer of the appropriate type). Though, how does one distinguish between the two errors? What I'd like to do, for example, is return `-1` if there's not enough data to cluster and `-2` if there's data, but none of them fit into a cluster (or some similar thing). In Python, this is easy enough (because it isn't statically typed). Even with `mypy`, I can say something like `typing.Union[UserLocation, int]`.

But, how does one do this in, say, C++ or Java? Would a Java programmer need to do something like set the function to return `int`, and return the ID of `UserLocation` instead of the object itself (then, whatever code uses the `get_user_location` function would itself do the lookup)? Is there runtime benefit to doing this, or is it just restructuring the code to fit the fact that a language is statically typed?

I believe I understand most of the obvious benefits of static typing w.r.t. code readability, compile-time, and efficiency at runtime—but I'm not sure what to make of this particular issue.

In a nutshell: How does one deal with functions (which return a non-basic type) indicating they ran into different errors in statically typed languages?

Comment: Various ways (~ "any which way that works"). For a number of C++ approaches see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157098/whats-the-right-approach-to-return-error-codes-in-c

Comment: Sounds like you need exceptions rather than return values.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In the case where a function is expected to fail for multiple cases, how does one differentiate between different cases/failures? (Is that a case when `std::variant` would be used?)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah! Excellent. Thank you. :) If you put your comments into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I should mention that you are somehow forgetting about exceptions as one of the error handling mechanisms. Returning some sort of `std::variant` or `std::optional` implies that caller is responsible for unpacking of result and inspection of valid value or reported error data which is often not desired. Also you should probably check Ada / Spark as a proper statically typed language. C/C++ is rather permissive.

Comment: Exceptions are commonly used for error handling. `None` usually indicates the absence of a resource. If there is not enough data to cluster, i.m.o. it's cleaner to let the `ValueError` propagate instead of excepting it in the function and returning `None`. Returning `None` means that no user location could be determined, not that there was nothing to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct C++ equivalent to the python solution would be `std::variant<T, U>` where `T` is the expected return value and `U` the error code type. You can then check which of the types the variant contains and go from there. For example :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using t_error_code = int;

// Might return either `std::string` OR `t_error_code`
std::variant<std::string, t_error_code> foo()
{
    // This would cause a `t_error_code` to be returned
    //return 10;

    // This causes an `std::string` to be returned
    return "Hello, World!";
}

int main()
{
    auto result = foo();

    // Similar to the Python `if isinstance(result, t_error_code)`
    if (std::holds_alternative<t_error_code>(result))
    {
        const auto error_code = std::get<t_error_code>(result);
        std::cout << "error " << error_code << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << std::get<std::string>(result) << std::endl;
}
```

However this isn't often seen in practice. If a function is expected to fail, then a single failed return value like a `nullptr` or `end` iterator suffices. Such failures are expected and aren't errors. If failure is unexpected, exceptions are preferred which also eliminates the problem you describe here. It's unusual to both expect failure and care about the details of why the failure occurred.